# A Question in Subspace topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

For a subspace $A$ of $\Bbb R^2$, how to show that

> a set $O\subset A $ is open in the subspace topology if and only if for each $x \in O$ there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that all points of $A$ of distance less than $\epsilon$ from $x$ lie in $O$

if $O$ is open in $A$ so $O=B \cap A$ that $B$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: You want to prove that the intersection of two open sets is also open?

Comment: @tampis the box is original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So left to right: assume $O$ is open in $A$, so there exists some open $O'$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, such that $O'\cap A = O$. Now, if $x \in O$, $x \in O'$ as well. There is some $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with distance less than $\epsilon$ we have that $x \in O'$, by the definition of open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that this $\epsilon$ works.

Right to left: suppose $O$ satisfies the condition. Then for each $x \in O$, fix its $\epsilon_x$ as in the condition. Define $O ' = \cup \{B(x, \epsilon_x): x \in O \}$, where $B(x,r)$ denotes the open ball around $x$ of radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $O'$ is  open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $O' \cap A = O$, so that $O$ is open in $A$.